# Laravel installer throws error when creating new project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, composer-php

I am trying to create new Laravel application.

I have installed XAMPP and Composer.
With Composer ( `composer global require laravel/installer` ) I have installed Laravel.

But when I try to use `laravel new firstProject` command to create new command the instalation throws two errors.

I am using Windows 10 if that helps.

```
 [RuntimeException]
  The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesys
  tems): ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\Users\User1\Desktop\PHP/vendor/composer/374ddf59/laravel-laravel-8e55104\public/rob
  ots.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

  [ErrorException]
  ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\Users\User1\Desktop\PHP/vendor/composer/374ddf59/laravel-laravel-8e55104\public/robots.txt
  ): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I have tried:

1. Reinstalling and updating composer
2. Reinstalling and updating Laravel
3. Changing folder where I want to create my project
4. Using the composer create-project laravel/laravel blog command to create new project through composer still the same errors as above

FIXED: I had to disable antivirus and add Laravel as exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read with understanding:

`Failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

---

This means that your command line have no access to read or write in current directory. You have to change directory permissions and it should work.

[change permissions on windows](https://v2cloud.com/tutorials/how-to-change-folder-permissions-on-windows-2016)

[change permissions on mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1203/mac)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I actually am logged in as Administrator, I have full control over the whole system.
but I can only create Laravel project in the system32 folder (Just discovered). Don't know why tho.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Win10).

In my case, my antivirus (Avast) was denying access to composer, but I did not know because I had set Avast to silent mode, so it just denied permission without asking me.

Also, Avast quaranteened an important server.php file so artisan server would stop as soon as I tried loading a page. So I had to restore and allow that file too.

Answer (score 0):

i have the solution.

You only need delete in c:\program file\7-Zip,

after you need, reinstall this software. 7-zip, You need download this software of webpage author.

after execute

laravel new your_app

and ready.

Comment: But here [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.ziparchive.php) is used for extraction, not 7zip. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31684469)